# Basic Identity Provider in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, saml, claims-based-identity

I'm going to be undertaking a large project for a client of mine.  I need to write an IDP (identity provider) that will handle single-sign-on to multiple apps by a number of different authentication methods (such as `SAML`, `OAuth`, `Form-based auth`, `HTTP Basic auth`).  I'd also need the ability to add in additional types of authentication as the app grows.

The basic idea would be that we'd have three different components to the app. One would be the IDP.  Another would be a data-store that contains user accounts, the apps they want to use, etc. The third would be a GUI front-end that allows users to sign into apps.

It seems that there are some existing gems that handle authentication, like https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml and https://github.com/intridea/omniauth.  My question is, am I overcomplicating this project -- would I just be able to use existing gems like these to act as the IDP, or is this a project where I'd need to read specs and implement them myself in Ruby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using something like [SAML toolkit for Ruby on Rails adapted to work with ADFS server](https://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-saml-bm), you can integrate with ADFS. Now you can leverage ADFS features:

- Interface with Facebook etc. via Azure ACS
- Interface with Azure Active Directory and hence SSO to SaaS applications
- Azure Active Directory Multi Factor Authentication
- BYOD via the Web Applications Proxy
- OAuth on ADFS 3.0

and so on. The list is expanding all the time.

Once you hook into these standards. you just inherit all the new features as they are released.